# como hago una consulta de mi base de datos?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta de mi base de datos

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Administracion\edicionCliente.php on
>   line 10

Este es mi código:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Consultando Cliente...</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "  SELECT NIT, nombre_Cliente FROM cliente WHERE nombre_Cliente = ?";

/*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de result */
    $stmt->bind_result($NIT, $nombre_Cliente);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "

    <div align='center'>
        <table border='1' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Consultando funcionarios</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales,
                de los funcionarios.</td>
            </tr>
            <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' disabled=”disabled”  name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$NIT."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' disabled=”disabled” name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$nombre_Cliente."'></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        <input type='button' value='Volver de donde viniste!' onclick='history.back(-2)' /> 
    </div>
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo '<script>
                    alert("El cliente no existe");
         </script>';
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la pregunta es, existe ?

Comment: Podrías agregar el formulario en el cual envías la información?

Comment: te falto también cerrar la etiqueta de cierre de php o sea ?>

Answer (score 0):

El problema que presentas es que cuando cargas la pagina.. 
Las variables por POST no existen..

La recomendacion es que hagas una validacion antes

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST != NULL){
     //Aqui va tu codigo php de consulta a la base de datos
}
```

Comment: y en que parte agrego esto?

Comment: Tu código desde la linea 10 en adelante, debería ir dentro de lo que te dije.. Pero tienes otro tema, que de esa forma no te mostrara ningún formulario en la vista.

Comment: sigue votando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

el error esta en

> $id = $_POST['id'];

revisa si estas enviando correctamente la id

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable "id" esta no definida en null, asegúrate que este trayendo algún dato del formulario anterior.

> if( isset($_POST['id']) ){
>   // si tiene dato
>   }else{ 
>   // no tiene dato 
>   }

Comment: Gian, bienvenid@ a SOes. Por recomendacion general, has el [tour]. Si pudieras explicar como es que el error esta relacionado con tu solucion, creo que seria bueno.

Comment: isset — Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en $id = $_POST['id']

Comment: Si tiene un error, creo que deberías indicar cuál y cómo resolverlo. El mensaje de error apunta a la línea 10, que es la que estás citando. No obstante, la idea es responder a la pregunta, teniendo como objetivo que las publicaciones deberían apuntar a tener la mayor calidad posible. Más info en [answer].